# vb.net console in a do loop

Tags: vb.net, console, console-application

I've written a fairly simple console app to check an Exchange email box every 30 seconds. When it's not running the check routine, it's in an empty do/loop in the Main method just to keep the program running. I find that that is taking a whole lot more of the server's resources (around 50%) than I expected.

Here's the Main method:

```
 Sub Main()
    GetSettings()
    tmrCheckInterval.Interval = 30000
    tmrCheckInterval.Start()
    WriteToConsole("Scan app started")
    Do
    Loop

End Sub
```

I don't do very many console apps, so I am not sure if this is the most efficient way, and I have struck out with a Google search. Is there an alternative process that will keep the app running without consuming resources?

Thanks...

Comment: How about launching your app from Task Scheduler once every n minutes and running it healthily once from start to end, no loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want this to run every 30 minutes, you are **much** better off removing the loop entirely and instead [setting up a Scheduled Task.](https://www.digitalcitizen.life/how-create-task-basic-task-wizard)

But as to why this code uses so much CPU... the program is doing work. It has a tight loop that never stops and never yields the CPU. It sits near 50% because you have a dual-core CPU and this uses all of one core. If you had a quad-core, it would use 25%. In the bad old single core days, this would use **all** of the CPU and even bringing up the task manager to kill the app could be challenging. I'm gonna have nightmares tonight remembering those times, so thanks for that.

I know it seems like you set an interval in this code, but that interval only applies to the timer, and is not part of the loop body. You want something more like this:

```
 Sub Main()
    GetSettings()
    WriteToConsole("Scan app started")
    Do
       'Remove the timer and call it's elapsed code directly here.

       Thread.Sleep(30 * 60 * 1000)
    Loop

End Sub
```

And again, this is still not as good as just using a scheduled task.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks! I prefer the [thread.sleep] method because the console displays feedback information as it is running.

Comment: @BillNorman Much better practice is writing that data to a log. This could be a file, a database, the Windows event log, or linux syslog service, but you don't want this running all the time. It **will** come back to bite you.

Comment: Can you elaborate?

Comment: Yes. One area this will come to bite is that .Net uses a generational, pressure-activated garbage collector that's not friendly to long-running programs. That makes writing service-style software for .Net a special discipline that requires careful understanding of all memory use. Otherwise, over time this program can end up consuming much "dead" memory from your system, or it can end up with uncompacted address space that eventually crashes the program.

Comment: Also, the sleep method here is just a crutch. You still have tight loop that's burning excessive extra CPU time (and battery for laptops) that's just not needed. It may not show up on the task manager, but it's still a thread that wakes up, asks for time, and forces context switches away from other tasks. And it's imprecise. There's no accounting here for the time it takes to actually check Exchange, so the timing here will tend to drift. A scheduled task corrects for that.

Comment: There's more, too. That's just what comes to the top of my head.

Comment: With regards to using a log being better practice... Logs allow you to monitor the results even when not at the computer. They let you check history, or 
be used to send alerts. They let you correlate issues across multiple runs of an application. Generally, they're more efficient. They can allow you to administer an app like this for multiple users.

Comment: Good advice, thanks. One more question... what if I made it a Windows Form application? Seems like overkill for a process as simple as that, but would that avoid the pitfalls you mentioned for a console app?

Comment: No, it would not. The same issue exist. What you can do is make a Windows Forms app that lives mostly as a system tray icon... but you _still_ need to be very careful about memory use.